# Can I make my USB stick even smaller?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-3, usb-2

I had this 8GB flash drive for years that I always kept in my coin purse in my wallet. It's tiny and thin. It used to be a normal flash drive with metal casing until the casing broke apart and eventually resulted in it being stripped of it. It still works as intended (on the right in the photo).

I recently got a 128gb flash drive (left) and I was wondering if I can take it apart and make it as slim as my previous one. Will such a thing be possible? It's already small but just too fat to comfortably fit in my wallet.

[image]

Comment: "*...eventually resulted in that*". Resulted in what? What does the picture represent?

Comment: @CharlieRB fixed

Comment: Is this 128GB Lexar a USB3.0, or USB2.0 drive?

Comment: @AliChen it's a 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB devices have the metal shroud for a reason - to protect data signals from ESD - ElectroStatic Discharge. By removing the shield you expose signal pins to ESD, which will definitely increase the risk of damaging the USB interface permanently and losing all your data. If you want to gamble with your data, you sure can remove everything.

Comment: What can be the main sources of ESD? How come it never happened to my unprotected flash drive for years given the fact that I use it almost on a daily basis?

Comment: Your old flash drive is probably USB2.0. USB3.0 speeds are much faster and more prone to interference.

Comment: @BrydonGibson thanks for the clarification! Why exactly would a faster flash drive be prone to interference more?

Comment: Technically speaking, USB3 transceivers are 10X faster than USB2, and therefore must have somewhat proportionally smaller transistor feature sizes. And protective ESD circuitry must have 10x less capacitance to pass 2.5GHz signals, as compared to 240MHz for USB2. Smaller transistors are more prone to ESD damage. The main source of ESD would be a charge accumulated on metal connectors due to friction in your pocket, relative to essentially grounded USB host port.

Answer (score 3):

The effect of static electricity from your body being discharge through an electronic device can be profound.

USB Flash Drives are built to limit the effects of Electrostatic Discharge but are not foolproof. In low humidity conditions, generating static electricity by shuffling across a rug and plugging *any device* into the USB port can destroy both the device and the USB port itself. It may also effect USB components inside the computer.

Because most electronic devices are protected from the risks of ESD damage, both internally and externally, we get complacent. A static discharge may not even be noticed. Typical internal component protection is around 2kV (2,000 Volts). By contrast, a static discharge that you can just feel in your finger is around 8-12kV (8,000-12,000, Volts). The static discharges that really hurt are more like 25kV (25,000 Volts).

Taking the 'guts' out of a flash drive only makes the problem more likely to happen. Perhaps nothing has seem to happen in the past, but ESD can silently degrade an electrical component's operation, causing premature failure.

Placing the drive's internal parts in a piece of aluminum foil or an ESD bag will reduce the chances of a problem. ( Anti-static bags do not help. They just do not generate static on their own.)

A very small USB flash drives on a key ring may be a safer alternative!

Comment: The question: "Can I make my USB stick even smaller"? Your response is not an answer, rather an educated opinion, and should be a comment. :)

Comment: @Xavierjazz You are correct ;)  - makes sense, but I wanted to add something to clear up confusion. I'm way short on reputation to be able to comment. Many times I feel this frustration, especially when I need clarification on a question!!

Comment: No, the answer by Jim is not an opinion, but an engineering explanation for reasons why USB connectors are ENGINEERED to have metal shrouds. As a matter of fact, USB connectors without metal shrouds are illegal from USB Specification and Certification standpoints, for the stated reasons.

Comment: "8-12kV (800-1200 Volts)" – to be fixed.

Comment: @AliChen then that should be in the answer, it isn't right now.